# Stop banner on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a banner on my site, but I can't make the banner stop on mouseover. I just tried `mouseover` and `hover` with jQuery. I expect to stop the banner on mouseover

```js
function mostrarBanner(indice) {
  clearInterval(executar);
  $('.carousel-banner .item-carousel').css({
    'opacity': '0',
    'z-index': '0'
  });

  $('.carousel-banner .item-carousel').eq(banner).css({
    'opacity': '1',
    'z-index': '1'
  });

  executar = setInterval(function() {
    $('.carousel-banner .next').trigger('click');
  }, 1000);

  $('#banner').hover(function() {
    console.log("DENTRO");
  }, function() {
    console.log("FORA");
  });
}

var executar = setInterval(function() {
  $('.carousel-banner .next').trigger('click');
}, 1000);

var banner = 0;
mostrarBanner(banner);
```

Comment: To debug this we would ideally need to see a working example of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So either you need to cancel the interval and recreate it or you can just use a variable to not call the code.

```
  var paused = false
  executar = setInterval(function() {
    if (paused) return
    $('.carousel-banner .next').trigger('click');
  }, 1000);

  $('#banner').hover(function() {
    paused = true
  }, function() {
    paused = false
  });
```